# Filling Char* in struct field (list)

Tags: c, arrays, list, pointers, struct

I'm having troubles passing by working on a list with "int" keys to a "char *" keys.
the `struct` looks like :

```
struct nodo {
char *info;
struct nodo *prec;
struct nodo *succ;
};
typedef struct nodo nodo;
```

and I'm trying to use a function i used a lot to fill a `struct` with int or float fields (adapted obviously):

```
struct nodo *Crealista(void) {
    struct nodo *p, *primo, *back;
    int i, n;
    p = NULL;
    primo = NULL;
    back = NULL;
    printf("Numero di elementi: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    assert(n!=0);
    printf("inserisci %d numeri interi positivi: ", n);

for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    p = malloc(sizeof(struct nodo));
    scanf("%c" /* or maybe s? i need a string for each nodo... */, p->info); 
  // i feel this is the line that needs some more work
    p->prec = back;
    p->succ = NULL;
    if (p->prec)
        p->prec->succ = p;
    back = p;
}

     primo = p;

     while (primo != NULL && primo->prec != NULL)
         primo = primo->prec;

return primo;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `&` in `scanf` in the line you mentioned,

```
        scanf(" %c", &p->info);
```

and give a space before `%c` in format string to `" %c"` so that it display text in format you want.

Comment: in addition to this, `Crealista` will need to `malloc` an array and assign its address to `p->info` before the `scanf`.  It would also be useful to restict the number of characters that `scanf` accepts to avoid overflowing the allocated memory.